# Multiple people playing a game using events in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, events, event-handling

I am creating one of those games where there are 2 players, each controlling their seperate blocks which move up and down, and a ball bouncing around, with the objective to get the ball behind the players' units and touch the wall (Its a game on Wii Play if that helps =D)

The problem I face is that I use events, such as `Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown`. Simple stuff.

Now before, I have only made single player games so this wasn't too much of an issue(but it inhibited me from moving diagonally etc. as 2 separate events weren't handled together, they were handled separately). So what is the question? Well, with two players, pressing multiple keys at the same time, how will this be handled?

TL;DR: There are multiple key events occurring at the same time. How do I handle them all at once?

Comment: Perhaps a timer would be suitable here? Maybe to check what's been/has not been pressed within the last 100ms etc.

Comment: For games, better look into DirectX - you get sophisticated drawing, responsive keys and much more flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this.  When multiple keys are pressed at the same time,  the `Form.KeyDown` event will be raised multiple times, once per key, so you can keep track of the current state of each key as the `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` events are raised.  Alternatively, you could do something similar by adding a `KeyMessageFilter` to the application's message filters by using the `Application.AddMessageFilter` method.  Keeping track, yourself, of each key's state like this may make sense if you have to inspect many keys and do so very often, however, the much simpler approach, and possibly just as efficient, would be to simply check the state of each key as necessary using either the `Keyboard.IsKeyDown` method (.NET framework 3.0 and later) as recommended by Joseph Lee, or by using the Win32 API call `GetKeyState` in user32.dll (pre-3.0 framework).

To answer your question in the comment below, user32.dll is a standard windows library.  It's one of a list of standard libraries which are collectively referred to as the Win32 API.  It's been around for as long as Windows, even before 95.  It's an unmanaged library, meaning, in simple terms, that it is not written in .NET and does not use the .NET framework.  They are essentially the means by which you directly communicate with the Windows OS.

Many of the methods provided in the .NET framework are simply wrappers around the old Win32 API calls.  If a managed class in the .NET framework provides the same functionality, you almost always want to use that instead of the Win32 API call.  There are multiple reasons why the managed libraries are preferred to the Win32 API:

- Ideally, .NET apps are supposed to be OS-independent.  If you make a call to a Win32 API call, that makes your application only run under Windows and, more specifically, only under versions of Windows that specifically support that API call.
- Calling unmanaged code requires some behind-the scenes data marshaling, so it is not as fast as calling managed code.  Many of the methods in the .NET framework have been implemented entirely in managed code, so no behind-the-scenes calls to unmanaged code is actually necessary.
- The managed libraries are just plain easier to use.  They are object-oriented and use standard data types.  Many of the Win32 API calls use pointers and custom structures which can make it difficult, though not impossible, to call them.

Therefore, if you are developing your app against the 3.0 version of the framework, or later, I would recommend using the `Keyboard` class, since it is managed code.  I would only use the Win32 API unless the other options won't work for you.

Comment: Hi Steven, thanks for the answer. Since I'm a complete newb(like I've already said in previous responses) what is this user32.dll! D:

Comment: I updated my answer, let me know if that doesn't answer your question :)

Comment: Hi Steven, thanks, that cleared up a bunch of doubts. So I decided to go with the Keyboard.IsKeyDown method, but for some reason intellisense doesn't help me and it gives an error. Do I need to import something?

Comment: Yes, you need to target the 3.0 framework, or later.  You need to reference the PresentationCore.dll library.  And you also need to add `Imports System.Windows.Input` to the top of your code file.

Comment: Hi Steven, thanks for that. I was able to get it up and working. Thanks for your time! :D

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are doing this through a Windows Application (and not a website).

To handle multiple keypress concurrently, you cannot do this via the Key events.
Instead, create a Timer object that fires/execute a function (very rapidly).
In that function, use the Keyboard class in the System.Windows.Input namespace, specifically the isKeyDown() method.

```
If Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Up) And Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Right) Then
    'Do something to move Up-right
End If
```

cheers.

Comment: Hmm...So I'd just need a bunch of if statements within the timer?

Comment: yupe, can be as simple as just a bunch of If statements. But I'd suggests you don't actually move the picture in the if statements.
Instead, perform location updates (ie, X = X+1: Y=Y-1) inside the If.

Then, after all the If are done (and thus, the final location of the object is determined), you show the picture at the X,Y coordinate.

Comment: Fortunately, I have moved past the stage where Im doing the location stuff (which you're telling me to avoid) within the if statement and I do perform what you've suggested. Good suggestion, Thanks! :)

Comment: Hi,

I am unable to use that method - Keyboard.IsKeyDown methods. Do I need to import something?

Answer (score 1):

I heard that people use GetAsyncKeyState for handling keys in games. Here is my tiny example for you:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1
    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Public Shared Function GetAsyncKeyState(ByVal vKey As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Short
    End Function
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim keyhandler As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf handlekeys)
        keyhandler.Start()
    End Sub

    Sub handlekeys()
        While True
            If GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.Up) Then
                'do something if up arrow key is being pressed
            ElseIf GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.Down) Then
                'do something if down arrow key is being pressed
            End If
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
        End While

    End Sub
End Class
```

This allows you to handle multiple keys at once. Also, you may use a timer instead of a thread with sleep.

Comment: Hi theGD, thanks for you answer. Since I'm a complete newb(and the next question will sound like it) what exactly does DllImport do? And also what is the shared function & the threading.thread stuff?

Comment: Well, Dllimport here, calls a function in a dll which is provided to you by Windows, that allows you to check whether a key is pressed or not. The rest of the question is hard to answer. Threading is a very long story. But for this case, you are checking each key in an infinite loop, BUT without blocking your graphical user interface. Because everything you see in a window is handled by a thread. Thus, if you put an infinite loop to that thread, graphical contents never get their turns to be handled. Which means you would see your window frozen without doing this with threading.